How did Moldaver survive to the present day?
We know that Moldaver lived about 200 years before the events of the series, before the bombs were dropped that turned California into a Wasteland.
Now, we have only seen two means of surviving that long in the show:

 being a ghoul, or being cryogenically frozen as one of Bud's Buds. If Moldaver were a ghoul, she would be the best-preserved one ever; freezing technology seems to only have been used by Vault-Tec, and Moldaver was far from their good graces when the bombs fell.

How did she survive for over 200 years?

I believe at this point it's not known why/how she survived that long

You know your post is spoileriffic? And unanswerable too - you apparently watched all of the thing (and real fast, at that). We can guess she used cryogenics - she did have access to advanced tech.

@Mithoron - It's a perfectly good question which may well have an answer in an interview or some easy to miss background aspect. No need to downvote because of spoilers, either: you can edit to hide them if you want.

@Adamant I didn't down vote, but IMHO someone with your rep should be able to recognize by now when a spoiler tag is needed.  Especially for a show that only dropped recently.

@PeterM - Someone who is still watching Fallout probably should not be reading questions about it.

@Adamant Someone watching the TV show may not know at what point in the series the question was posed.  I'll happily read questions that explain what I have previously watched, as I have never played the games.  It's just common curtesy to protect other people from inadvertently reading something too soon.

@Adamant I tried hiding spoilers in title and text as much as I could without ruining your question, feel free to correct if you think I've gone too far :)

@AndresF. - I kept all your changes but the title. It seems unnecessarily obscure, especially since we learn about Moldaver early in the show, and people will guess who "M." refers to anyway (obviously not Magnus).

In an interview with Nerdist, Sarita Choudhury, the actress who portrays Moldaver, was asked this very question. While she couldn't reveal the exact reason, Choudhury did tease that she knows the secret behind Moldaver's longevity, hinting that it will likely be explored in the show's second season (emphasis mine):

Nerdist: One thing I know a lot of people are really curious to know about is how Moldaver survived from the before times to the after times in Fallout. Is there anything you can share about how she made it through the nuclear apocalypse and the 200 years after it?
Choudhury: I can’t, but I like your predictions, and you can figure stuff out, I think. But again, it’s in line with the fact that she’s a scientist. The fact that she created cold fusion makes me think she can figure out how to live.

While the exact details remain a mystery for now, it seems Moldaver's scientific knowledge will play a key role in explaining her longevity. 

If it is something that cannot be revealed now, it probably has some ongoing relevance. Either because other people might have used the same method, or because revealing it might imply that she is not actually dead. For instance, if Moldaver were actually a clone of the original, we might expect to see more clone Moldavers in the next season.
